# What difference between using ScopedDisposable and take(during: ...)?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I have View Controller which has some signal and I want to observe values from that signal in `viewDidLoad()`. I need to dispose that signal when View Controller will be dead:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let composite = CompositeDisposable()
    defer {
        disposable = ScopedDisposable(composite)
    }
    composite += someSignal.take(during: self.reactive.lifetime).observeValues { ... }
}
```

Does it necessary to add result of `viewModel.alertSignal.take(during: self.reactive.lifetime).observeValues ...` to ScopedDisposable object as I do in code: `composite += ...`? Or just call `take(during: self.reactive.lifetime)` is enough?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `disposable` is a property of your ViewController, it does the same thing as `take(during:)` so you can use whichever you like, but you don't need to use both!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let composite = CompositeDisposable()
    defer {
        disposable = ScopedDisposable(composite)
    }
    composite += someSignal.observeValues { ... }
}
```

or

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    someSignal.take(during: self.reactive.lifetime).observeValues { ... }
}
```

I personally prefere to use `take(during:)` since its just less code.

Answer (score 1):

`take(during:)` will make the signal send completed event when lifetime gets deallocated. That means following events will happen:

`Deinit -> Completed event -> Terminated event -> Disposed event`

When using ScopedDisposable flow will look like this:

`Deinit -> Interrupted event -> Terminated event -> Disposed event`

It's important to understand this difference because in the first case it's unsafe to access lifetime owner (usually self) in `on(completed: () -> void)` because once it's completed owner is already deallocated!